# PHP: In Exception what's the purpose of the exception code?

Tags: php

Can this be any number I choose for my personal liking (my own set of codes for my app) or is it suppose to be standard number codes?

For reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.getcode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It allows you to differenciate between errors. Say you have a code that throws the same Exception for multiple errors, you can use the optional 'code' parameter in the object declaration to differenciate between them.

In the example on that page, they call a new Exception with a code of 30, so when you check the object outputted, it returns '30'.

eg:

```
try {
    if ($something) {
        throw new Exception("Generic Error",1);
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception("Generic Error #2",2);
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error ID ".$e->getCode()." was thrown.";
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it appears to be any arbitrary number that we can use. Is there a recommended standard/set of numbers kinda like HTTP status codes?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It's just a component of the Exception object, and is entirely for customised use. Naturally, I'm sure some frameworks will likely have their own error code specifications, but it's entirely up to the author otherwise.

Comment: A common use is to forward error codes from external sources, for example MySQL-related classes might throw exceptions with the corresponding code numbers coming from the underlying MySQL libraries.